# Make a sum of values for items that are the same in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array stored in a variable $data. The array has countries in the first row and a value in the second row. The problem is that a country may be inserted in the array multiple times but with different values. When this happens I need a solution to display the country and the sum of all its entries in this array. For example

```
$data(array): 
data=>
    [0]=>
        array(1447) {
          [1]=>
          array(3) {
            [0]=>
            string(11) "France"
            [1]=>
            string(1) "11"
          }
          [2]=>
          array(3) {
            [0]=>
            string(7) "Italy"
            [1]=>
            string(1) "28"
          }
          [3]=>
          array(3) {
            [0]=>
            string(6) "France"
            [1]=>
            string(1) "50"
          }
          [4]=>
          array(3) {
            [0]=>
            string(6) "France"
            [1]=>
            string(1) "22"
          }
          [5]=>
          array(3) {
            [0]=>
            string(6) "Germany"
            [1]=>
            string(1) "1"
          }
          [6]=>
          array(3) {
            [0]=>
            string(6) "Romania"
            [1]=>
            string(1) "5"
          }
```

In this case I should display: France 83, Italy 28, Germany 1, Romania 5. So since France has three entries I need to display the sum of all the entries...like sum of `$data->data[0][1][1] + $data->data[0][3][1] + $data->data[0][4][1]`, this is how I call the values. This translates into: 11 + 50 + 22 = 83.
Thank you all in advance. I am at the beginning of my journey into back-end and stackoverflow, so if I made a mistake or my question is not clear enough I am sorry.

Comment: Make a simple `foreach` and check `[0]` element of each array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// array to store sums
$sums = array(); 
// iterate over each element of $data[0]
foreach ($data[0] as $item) {
    // get country name
    $country = $item[0];
    // if there's no such country name key in $sums - make it with value 0
    if (!isset($sums[$country])) {
        $sums[$country] = 0;
    }

    // add value to current country key
    $sums[$country] += $item[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with `array_reduce`:

```
$result = array_reduce($data[0], function($sums, $x) {
    $sums[$x[0]] = (isset($sums[$x[0]]) ? $sums[$x[0]] : 0) +$x[1];
    return $sums;
});
```

If you have PHP 7, a country's sum can be incremented within the callback more neatly using:

```
$sums[$x[0]] = ($sums[$x[0]] ?? 0) + $x[1];
```

---

I think it's also worth mentioning that this is operation is equivalent to `GROUP BY` with `SUM` in SQL, and if the array you are working with is the result of an SQL query, it would probably be better to change the query to do this rather than doing it in PHP, something like:

```
SELECT country_name, SUM(name_of_number_column) AS country_total
FROM your_country_table GROUP BY country_name
```

(Of course, I made up the table and column names for this example.)